# Unknown Words in N-Gram Modelling

Tags: nlp, n-gram, smoothing

What is the logic for grouping unknown words under the same token i.e., `<UNK>` and also include words with small probabilities?

Won't some rare words get assigned high probabilities if the `<UNK>` set grows in size?

This might work if all the `<UNK>` words belong to the same class in some sense, for example, proper nouns such as John, Tim, Sam can all use each other's probability as bi-grams "Hello John, Hello Tim, Hello Sam" are equally likely. But if this is not the case, won't this method run into problems?

Comment: Why should the probabilities for unknown words rise when “the `<UNK>` set grows in size”? The probabilities are estimated and fixed in the training, when there are (by definition) no unknown tokens/n-grams.

Comment: Magic word is smoothing https://nlp.stanford.edu/~wcmac/papers/20050421-smoothing-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Mapping rare words to `<UNK>` simply means that we delete those words and replace them with the token `<UNK>` in the training data. Thus our model does not know of any rare words. It is a crude form of smoothing because the model assumes that the token `<UNK>` will never actually occur in real data or better yet it ignores these n-grams altogether.

The problem that smoothing is trying to solve is data sparsity. This technique is probably the simplest way to deal with it. However, we can do [better](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~wcmac/papers/20050421-smoothing-tutorial.p%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdf) as @alvas shows in the comments.

Comment: Link is broken.